# Spark on AWS EMR - Dynamic partition overwrite S3 / Glue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm using pyspark from an AWS EMR notebook and would like to overwrite a single partition when saving a table. Normally can do this with

```
df.write.mode('overwrite')\
            .option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")\
            .insertInto('table')
```

However this doesn't work when writing to S3. Is there a way to only overwrite the files in that S3 partition, as well as in the spark metadata?

Note: I am using Glue as the spark metadata

Comment: Find that hard to believe. What do you mean by overwrite not working. S3 is an object store and uses versioning.

Comment: .partitionBy clause missing?

Comment: @thebluephantom pretty sure .partitionBy gave an error saying that insertInto doesn't work with partitionBy in the same write statement. Furthermore, I believe the s3 path needs to be specified as a write option for it to actually get written to s3

Comment: Interesting.  Well I have used in non-S3 without an issue. S3 via AWS EMR via EMRFS can do that.  The S3 thing is indeed true!

Comment: partitionBy...I always use it anyway.

Comment: Yeah it was very strange when I was trying to get this to work on Friday. I was testing different table writes on a temporary table and got it to work (only overwrite the partition) but when I tried it with the real table it overwrote the whole thing :/

Answer (score 1):

Please check the spark version you are using. From version 2.3.0, Spark allows overwriting related partitions -> 'dynamic' mode but default setting is to use 'static' which will delete all the partition at the location.

From AWS documentation it looks like from EMR 5.21.0 onwards default behaviour is 'dynamic' mode. I verified that EMR 5.21.0 does not overwrite all the partition in the location by default.

[AWS doc:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html)
"The partitionOverwriteMode write option was introduced in Spark 2.4.0. For Spark version 2.3.2, included with Amazon EMR release 5.19.0, set the spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode property."